# JQuery: How do I determine if a slideToggle has been toggled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I do the following pseudo code in JQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#divToSlide").slideToggle("fast");
        if ($(this).isToggled) {  // <---- DOESN'T WORK -------
            // do something when toggled
        } else {
            // do something different when not toggled
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` is referring to `$(".btn-slide")` which is not toggled.... am i lost???

Comment: I believe you might be having a problem with the fact that it is an animation and possibly still in progress when you get to the `isToggled` part of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could just use the toggle function: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('#target').toggle(function() {
    alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
});
```

Note: You can have as many toggles as you want, just add more functions:

```
$('#target').toggle(function() {
    alert('1 handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('2 handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('3 handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('4 handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    alert('5 handler for .toggle() called.');
});
```

**[EDIT]**

```
$('a.toggleButton').toggle(function() {
    $("#divToSlide").slideDown("fast");
    // do something when toggled
}, function() {
    $("#divToSlide").slideUp("fast");
    // do something when toggled    });
});
```

Comment: with due respect, but that was not the question. Or, it is completly missleading.

Comment: How do I use your code since I'm using a SlideToggle on a click event?

Comment: toggle 1 would be slide down, and toggle 2 would be slide up in the first case.

Comment: I'm doing a SlideToggle, so wouldn't this be different than just a Toggle?

Comment: @jAndy: Fair enough, but he was looking for toggle functionality which this provides, so I believe that this would solve the problem that he is having

Comment: @jAndy , it seems that @Reigel agrees with me.

Comment: @SeanJA may I ask how did you know it was me?

Comment: @Reigel I was commenting that your answer was similar to mine actually

Answer (score 4):

Try using a callback function for slideToggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#divToSlide").slideToggle("fast", function(){
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {  // <---- DOESN'T WORK -------
            // do something when toggled
            }
            else {
            // do something different when not toggled
            }
        });
    });            
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        if ('#divToSlide').is(':visible')) {
            // do something when toggled
        } else {
            // do something different when not toggled
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I also tried *"if ($("#divToSlide").is(':visible')) {"* ... and the ELSE statement still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Question: "How do I determine if a slideToggle has been toggled?"

That is the answer to your original question, check the visible state of that element. done.

Comment: you can also say, if ('#divToSlide').is(':animated')

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#divToSlide").toggle(
        function() {  
            // do something when toggled
            $(this).slideUp();
        },
        function(){
            // do something different when not toggled
            $(this).slideDown();
        }
    );  
});
```

Comment: this looks promising but I think some of the "}" and ")" are misplaced near the end